# Sección footer en un informe de MS Access se salta a la segunda página al imprimir

Tags: ms-access-2010

Hice un informe en Access que es un recibo de compra, el cual muestra en el detalle los ítems comprados y el precio de cada uno. Luego en la sección pie de informe o footer, hace la sumatoria de precio total. Cuando veo el informe en vista previa se muestra completo con su footer en una sola página y no me da errores de márgenes.

Tengo que imprimir este informe o recibo en una impresora Epson tmu 220 pd. Ya configuré las medidas de la página. Cuando envío el informe me imprime el detalle completo sin problema, pero no me imprime el footer ¿dónde está el total?

Ahora viene lo mas raro: si le doy de nuevo a imprimir entonces me imprime el footer (los totales) -que no imprimió la primera vez- y luego del footer imprime de nuevo el recibo, pero -otra vez- sin el footer.

No es por las medidas porque si aumento los ítems en el detalle, me los imprime completos. El problema es que la sección footer no la imprime en la primera impresión sino en la segunda como lo describí. Es como si hiciera un corte de página justo cuando cambia la sección del informe de detalle a footer.

Comment: Hola @user1484358. Los usuarios de la comunidad brindarán respuestas de acuerdo a los conocimientos que posean sobre los temas tratados en la pregunta. Si nadie ha brindado una respuesta es porque quizás aún no hay usuarios que puedan hacerlo o quienes lo podrían hacer no han visto la pregunta (o quizás alguna otra razón X). La edición de publicaciones, sin embargo, es para pulir el contenido de las mismas, para facilitar su lectura, lo cual **no está directamente relacionado** con las respuestas que se brindan a una pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado -en otro foro- la respuesta a mi pregunta.

Primero:

Se configura la **impresora epson tmu220 como Generic/text only**. Esto ya lo había hecho pero no me imprimía el footer del informe de `Access`. Para corregir esa falla hay que configurar la impresora de la siguiente manera:

```
GENERIC Generic / Text Only
```

En el comando de la impresora :

```
Empezar trabajo de impresion <20> 
Finalizar trabajo de Impresion <0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A>
```

Configuración de Dispositivo

```
Alimentacion Continua: Continuo Americano Standart 
Cortar Hoja: Continuo Americano Standart 
Alimentacion Continua : No Disponible
```

Es todo. Hice mi aporte, ahora quedo a la espera de los "editores" que parece ser lo que abunda aquí más que la ayuda. Es mucho mejor el foro en inglés (Apuesto que este último párrafo es donde van a editar primero).

Comment: hola @user1484358, espero que tan pronto como puedas ver este mensaje aceptes tu respuesta, así ayudamos a mantener la salud del sitio :D